# TeamCity CppUnit plugin prints extra '\n'

Tags: c++, tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity, cppunit

I have integrated TeamCity with Cppunit using [their plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/Cpp+Unit+Test+Reporting).

I’m trying to get rid of the `'\n'` that’s being appended after each test. I tried commenting out `details.append("\n");` from teamcity_cppunit.cpp, but that didn’t do the trick. And I didn’t find anywhere else that `'\n'` is being appended.

Basically I want to get this :

```
16>  Description: Executing Unit Tests...
16>  Running 4 test cases...
16>  CoreTechUnitTests::CLogExtractorTestCase::CreateLogExtractorTest... [0.2503s]
16>  CoreTechUnitTests::CLogExtractorTestCase::CreateOutputFolderTest... [0.0057s]
16>  CoreTechUnitTests::CLogExtractorTestCase::WriteLogFileTest... [0.0050s]
16>  CoreTechUnitTests::CLogExtractorTestCase::LastRunUnitTest... [0.0001s]
16>  Total test execution took 0.2612s
16>  
16>  OK (4)
```

As opposed to this :

```
9>  CoreTechUnitTests::CMcMd5TestCase::MD5Test...CoreTechUnitTests::CMcMd5TestCase::MD5Test [0.0001s] : OK
9>  
9>  CoreTechUnitTests::CByteBufferTest::TestBuffer...CoreTechUnitTests::CByteBufferTest::TestBuffer [0.0003s] : OK
9>  
9>  CoreTechUnitTests::CETWLogConsumerTestCase::CreateETWReaderTests...CoreTechUnitTests::CETWLogConsumerTestCase::CreateETWReaderTests [0.0106s] : OK
9>  
9>  CoreTechUnitTests::CETWLogConsumerTestCase::ExtractEventSystemTimeTests...CoreTechUnitTests::CETWLogConsumerTestCase::ExtractEventSystemTimeTests [0.0001s] : OK
```

I was wondering if anyone knows where that `'\n'` is being appended.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an endl written to the output stream in teamcity_messages.cpp at line 71:

```
*m_out << endl;
```

Another place to look is in teamcity_boost.cpp at line 153:

```
out << endl;
```

See if removing one of these does the trick.

Comment: That didn't really fix the problem. Thanks for the answer though.